# how do i remove array in array

Tags: php, arrays

Sometimes, when I fetch something, I get the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 3803
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 3855
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 3855
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 3855
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => 3856
    )
)
```

But, what I actually need is:

```
Array ( [0] => 3803 [1] => 3855 [2] => 3855 [3] => 3855 [4] => 3856 )
```

So, I do this:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $data)
{
    array_push($new_array,$data[0]);
}
```

I'm not sure, if there is a better way. Maybe without making a new array?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: It worked. But I was looking for a more elegant way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shortest way. Try this:

```
$array = array(
    array("3803"),
    array("3855"),
    array("3855"),
    array("3855"),
    array("3856")
);

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => 3803
 [1] => 3855
 [2] => 3855
 [3] => 3855
 [4] => 3856
)
```

Comment: I guess, this is the shortest way, besides `array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', array());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    array_push($new_array,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) like,

```
$new_array = array();    
foreach ($array as $data)
{    
    $new_array = array_merge($new_array,$data);
}
```